# Redux Toolkit Migration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to migrate my app thay use redux, redux-thunk and redux-persist to reduxToolkit, but I don't know how to do it with my initial configuration, here my code:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default function getConfiguredStore(initialState, config) {
  const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
  let appReducer = rootReducer;
  if (config.usePersist) {
    appReducer = persistedReducer;
  }
  const rootAppReducer = authReducer(appReducer);

  const store = createStore(
      rootAppReducer,
      initialState,
      composeEnhancers(
          applyMiddleware(
              multiClientMiddleware(axiosConfig),
              thunkMiddleware,
              authMiddleware( ),
              createLogger( true ),
          )
      ),
  );
  const persistor = persistStore(store, null, () => {
    if (config.useLogger) {
      console.log('REHYDRATED');
    }
  });
  //persistor.purge() //TO clean state.

  return {store, persistor};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Modern Redux with Redux Toolkit" tutorial page](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) in the Redux docs shows how to migrate existing Redux logic to use RTK.  Summarizing:

- Replace your existing store setup logic with a call to `configureStore()`
- Pick a reducer and its associated actions. Replace with `createSlice`. Repeat as needed.

In your case, the key part would be to switch the `const store = createStore()` part for this:

```js
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootAppReducer,
    preloadedState: initialState,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => {
      return getDefaultMiddleware()
        .prepend(multiClientMiddleware(axiosConfig))
        .concat(authMiddleware, createLogger( true ));
    })
  });
```